# Set Task to Approved or Rejected from workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have a `Task` that was created by a 2013 workflow, through either the `Assign a task` command or `Start a task process` command.  I have a second workflow that wants to use `Update List Item` to approve or reject that `Task` when a specific condition occurs.

First, how do I find the appropriate `task`?  By selecting the `Tasks` list, the lookup allows me to find it by ID, but I don't have the ID of the task.

Second, the field/value combination only allows me to set the `Status` to `Completed`.  I don't see anything that allows me to set it to `Approved` or `Rejected`.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a field called `Approval Status` that I missed.  You can find the correct item by using the `Workflow Item ID`, which is the item related to the task.

edit: You can't update the Approval Status, only search on it.